# MKNetworkKit doesn't retrieve any images

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, mknetworkkit

```
NSString *pictureUrl = [[[oneUserDict objectForKey:@"picture"]objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"url"];

[[AppEngine sharedEngine]imageAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pictureUrl] onCompletion:^(UIImage *fetchedImage, NSURL *url, BOOL isInCache) 

{
  int index  = [usersArray indexOfObject:oneUserDict];
  NSString *loadName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %d",index,[usersArray count]];
  NSLog(@"%i",usersArray.count);
  int temp=[usersArray count]-10;

  if (index!=temp) 
  {

    [[LoadingIndicator currentIndicator]displayActivity:loadName];
    NSLog(@"inside loading indicator");
  }

  else
  {

   [[LoadingIndicator currentIndicator]displayCompleted:@"Done"];
     NSLog(@"finally done");
  }

    aPerson.image =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(fetchedImage);
    [appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:nil];
 }];
```

AppEngine is the subclass of `MKNetworkEngine` which uses a method called `imageAtURL:onCompletion:`

what I am currently doing is retrieving all the images from a particular url and and storing them in aPerson.image,basically the above code is in a FOR loop(i.e the for the count of users).

Issues

The above code which is in the completion block never gets executed,i dont know why but i have put a breakpoint inside the block but still the compiler wont run the statements inside the completion block.

Comment: Could you format your code to make it readable? It's difficult to follow...Thanks in advance.

Comment: @flexaddicted i formatted the code again,please let me know if you can help me out with this thanks

Comment: Can you `NSLog(@"%@",[NSURL URLWithString:pictureUrl]);` before initiating the image download request and check if they are not `nil`?

Comment: @Amar i get the URL,they arent nil

Comment: Api `imageAtURL:onCompletion:` is deprecated. Use `imageAtURL:completionHandler:errorHandler:` instead. Also `MKNetworkKit` provides for `UIImageView+MKNetworkKitAdditions` category which provides simple API for image download like `setImageFromURL: placeHolderImage:`.

Comment: @Amar thanks man you saved me..please put it as an answer,i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api `imageAtURL:onCompletion:` is deprecated. Use `imageAtURL:completionHandler:errorHandler:` instead. Also MKNetworkKit provides for `UIImageView+MKNetworkKitAdditions` category which provides simple API for image download like `setImageFromURL: placeHolderImage:`

Cheers!
Amar.